# Pandas groupby error on division

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given the sample data below, I am attempting to compute conditional probabilities.  The columns represent events A-E having occurred in a sequence (S1,S2...).

The first two examples work as expected and compute P(S2|S1) and P(S2,S3|S1).  The approach breaks when the conditioning includes multiple columns as in example three, which I expected would compute P(S3|S1,S2).

I'd appreciate both insight as to why this doesn't work and what alternative method could get the desired result of P(S3|S1,S2).  For example, I would expect the output to include rows `A,D,B,0.25` and `A,D,C,0.75`.

Thank you!

MWE code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = { 'S1' : ['A','A','A','B','B','A','A'],
         'S2' : ['B','D','D','A','D','D','D'],
         'S3' : ['C','C','C','D','C','B','C'],
         'S4' : ['D','B','E','C','A','C','E'] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print (df)
print ((df.groupby(['S1','S2']).agg({'S4':'count'}) /
        df.groupby('S1').agg({'S4':'count'})).rename(columns={'S4':'Freq'}))
print ((df.groupby(['S1','S2','S3']).agg({'S4':'count'}) / 
        df.groupby('S1').agg({'S4':'count'})).rename(columns={'S4':'Freq'}))
print ((df.groupby(['S1','S2','S3']).agg({'S4':'count'}) / 
       df.groupby(['S1','S2']).agg({'S4':'count'})).rename(columns={'S4':'Freq'}))
```

Output:

```
  S1 S2 S3 S4
0  A  B  C  D
1  A  D  C  B
2  A  D  C  E
3  B  A  D  C
4  B  D  C  A
5  A  D  B  C
6  A  D  C  E
       Freq
S1 S2      
A  B    0.2
   D    0.8
B  A    0.5
   D    0.5
          Freq
S1 S2 S3      
A  B  C    0.2
   D  B    0.2
      C    0.6
B  A  D    0.5
   D  C    0.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print ((df.groupby(['S1','S2','S3']).agg({'S4':'count'}) / df.groupby(['S1','S2']).agg({'S4':'count'})).rename(columns={'S4':'Freq'}))
NotImplementedError: merging with more than one level overlap on a multi-index is not implemented
```

Comment: *"I'd appreciate insight as to why this doesn't work"* - the error message says why it doesn't work.

Comment: It can not *Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous
*

Comment: I believe I agree with Wen.  It is possible pandas may be performing a merge or join under the hood, but that isn't what the user-level code is asking for.  The desired result is "for each item index S1,S2,S3, divide it by the count of all matching index S1,S2", i.e. a simple normalization constant for a conditional probability.  In any case, an alternate method to achieve the result would be very welcome!